# Updating Salesforce Date field with MC AmpScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have not been successful in updating a Salesforce Date or Date/Time field from AMPScript.  I've tried different formats but no success in either creating a new record or updating a existing record.  I've also tried Standard field vs customs fields and date fields vs. date/time fields.

```
set @date1 = Format(Now(),"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ")
set @date2 = Format(Now(),"YYYY-MM-DD")
set @date3 = Concat(DatePart(Now(),"Y"),"-",DatePart(Now(),"M"),"-",DatePart(Now(),"D"),"T00:00:00.000Z")

set @id= CreateSalesforceObject("Task", 5, "WhatId", @OpptyId, "WhoId", @ContactId, "Subject", "DATE1", "Status", "(3) Closed", "ActivityDate", @date1)
```

Answer (score 4):

The date value needs to be either "yyyy-MM-dd" or "iso" format.  But, are you sure none of the other values passed in your function are causing issue?

For testing purposes, I would recommend creating a call with as few parameters as possible.  Either of the following ampscript values should work as your ActivityDate value.

```
set @date1 = FormatDate(Now(),"YYYY-MM-DD")
```

or

```
set @date1 = FormatDate(Now(),"iso")
```

Comment: Thank you.  I confirmed it was the date parameter because the AMPscript works when I take the date field out of the call, creating the Task successfully.  In testing, I had used a separate call                                                                            set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Opportunity",@OpptyId),"CloseDate",@date1)    using both the standard field CloseDate and also a custom date field we have.  Neither would execute, even using the "YYYY-MM-DD' format.

Comment: However, I just tested your "iso" suggestion and it worked!   Success!  Thank you so much - I was exporting the Tasks and updating the date manually which was not a long term solution.  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: That is odd that the other date format didn't work.  Do you know what values was returned by FormatDate(Now(),"YYYY-MM-DD")?   If it does not return the expected value, you might try changing the YYYY and DD to lower case, but leave the MM as uppercase.  Here's a reference to the proper formatting of these parameters.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: When I displayed the dates in the email, they were correctly formated and based on the documentation, I thought they should have worked as well.